# Using "this" to call context in a fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm following a tutorial on youtube on building a timer application in Android Studio using Kotlin. The tutorial builds the timer in an Activity, but because I want my application to have multiple pages, I built it in a fragment. Unfortunately, some of the code requires calling context for methods in a separate companion object called PrefUtil. The tutorial uses "this" to call the context and it seems to work in an Activity, but when I try to do it in a fragment, it stops working.

I don't have prior Kotlin knowledge so I've just been looking online and trying everything to get my code to work. Nothing's worked.

```
PrefUtil.setPreviousTimerLengthSeconds(timerLengthSeconds, 
PrefUtil.setSecondsRemaining(secondsRemaining, 
PrefUtil.setTimerState(timerState, this)
```

"this" is supposed to describe the Context of the Activity, but when this returns my TimerFragment and returns an error

Comment: Use the `context` parameter of the Fragment in place of `this`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right. `this` represents context. But in a fragment, you have to use `getContext()` or `getActivity()` to use activity's context.

Comment: `this` is the object instance, in a Fragment it is a Fragment and in an Activity it is an Activity.  An Activity extends from Context, that is why in an Activity this is also a Context. Fragment doesn't extend from Context, it needs to get the context from the Activity it is attached to.

Comment: when we use getContext(), it says it requires "Context" and it found "Context?"

Comment: fragment's `getContext()` method has implementation like this:```@Nullable
    public Context getContext() {
        return mHost == null ? null : mHost.getContext();
    }``` and here mHost is activity. and so that `getContext()` provides activity's context

Comment: Or you could just use `requireContext()`. If your `PrefUtil` accepts a nullable type context, simply remove the nullable type.

Comment: if you find this answer useful, then do approve the answer

Comment: In Kotlin, you can use just `context` to call `getContext()`.